# how to handle divide by zero error in ML

Tags: error-handling, sml, ml, divide-by-zero

I am new to ML.

I need to define a function taking an conditional expression as argument, the problem is if the expression is invalid like `"10 div 0 = 0"`. How can I handle this?

For example, the function is defined as following: `foo exp1 = if (exp1) then ... else...`, and `exp1` is `"10 div 0 = 0"`, how to handle this division error.

Comment: can you post what normal syntax would look like in a code block so that perhaps someone could attempt to help you..

Comment: for example if I were to code something in C# I would use this type of syntax inline int roundDownDivide(int a, int b) {   if (a >= 0) return a/b;    else return (a-b+1)/b; }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want to ask about exception handling mechanism in SML.

The `div` function in SML basis library raise Div exception when you invoke `10 div 0`. It depends on whether you need the value or not to handle the exception. You can either return true/false or option type in this case:

```
(* only catch exception, ignore value *)
fun div_check (x, y) = (
  ignore (x div y);
  false
) handle Div => true

(* catch exception and return option value *)
fun div_check2 (x, y) = (
  SOME (x div y)
) handle Div => NONE
```

**UPDATE:**

It is really weird that the compiler doesn't raise `Div` exception in this case. I suggest that you define a custom div function and raise/handle exceptions yourself:

```
exception DivByZero;

(* custom div function: raise DivByZero if y is zero *)
infix my_div;
fun x my_div y =
  if y=0 then raise DivByZero else x div y

fun div_check (x, y) = (
  ignore (x my_div y);
  false
) handle DivByZero => true

fun div_check2 (x, y) = (
  SOME (x my_div y)
) handle DivByZero => NONE
```

Comment: Thanks, seems what I am looking for. But sml still gives me: './sml: Fatal error -- unexpected fault, signal = 8, code = 0x7' when I use the function like div_check (10, 0).

Comment: I checked with smlnj and got the same behaviour. Check my update for another solution.

Comment: This might be an SML/NJ bug from a particular version, or a particular platform.  I get `Div` raised correctly using v110.73 on OS X.

Comment: @Gian: I suspected the same but couldn't verify by searching on the Internet. Thanks for pointing it out.